# Limit bandwidth on a specific port in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, limit, bandwidth, port

I am running CentOS 7 on my VPS and I would like to limit bandwidth on a specific port. I have looked around extensively, and out of the solutions I can find, either it's a limit placed on an interface, or it's a vaguely described iptable setup that  seems to have only been tried on CentOS 6.

In my case, my Shadowsocks (a proxy application) serverside is listening on port `1080`, `1081`, and `1082` on `eth0`. I would like to allow `1080` unlimited bandwidth, but limit both `1081` and `1082` to around 1MBps. Since it's a proxy application the inbound and outbound traffic is roughly equal. Note that it is a single instance of Shadowsocks listening on 3 ports, **NOT** 3 instances listening on 1 port each, so limiting bandwidth by process is not applicable.

But otherwise any solution is on the table for me, whether it's something CentOS supports out of the box, or some kind of intermediate monitoring layer. As long as it gets the job done I'm open to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: handling UDP has some added challenge. Are some clients using SOCKS5 UDP ASSOCIATE, or is it TCP only? Are you trying to regulate mostly good behaving clients, or are you trying to protect from some attack?

Comment: @A.B I am only trying to regulate TCP. Also the clients are expected to be good behaving. It is a small private server so I do not expect it to be subject to deliberate attacks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traffic can be limited using only [Linux's Traffic Control](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/).

Just to clarify, [shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/) creates a tunnel with one side as a SOCKS5 proxy ([`sslocal`](https://manpages.debian.org/shadowsocks/sslocal.1), I'm assuming that's what is running on the OP's server considering the given ports), communicating with a remote endpoint ([`ssserver`](https://manpages.debian.org/shadowsocks/ssserver.1)) which will itself communicate with the actual target servers. shadowsocks handles SOCKS5 UDP ASSOCIATE, and uses then (SOCKS5) UDP on the same port as the (SOCKS5) TCP port.

This solution works as is <sup>(see note 1)</sup> for both TCP and UDP, except UDP might give additional challenges: if a source is creating "bigger than MTU" sized UDP packets (which probably shouldn't be done by a well behaving client or server), they get fragmented. *tc*, which works [earlier than *netfilter* in *ingress*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) and later than *netfilter* in *egress*, will see the fragments. The UDP port is not available in fragments, so no filter will be able to catch them and almost no limitation will happen. TCP naturally using MTU for packet size limit (and doing path MTU discovery anyway) doesn't suffer this issue in most settings.

Here's a packet flow ascii picture (the whole picture would typically represent one client activity resulting in two flows, one to the left and one to the right of the proxy):

```
              traffic controlled      TCP self-adjusting / no UDP control
             ------------->               <-------------
           /                \           /                \
  clients |                  |  proxy  |                  |  remote  ====== real servers
           \                / (sslocal) \                / (ssserver)
             <-------------               ------------->
              traffic controlled       already rate limited
```

There's no need or use to worry about the traffic with the remote server:

- outgoing from proxy to remote server will of course be limited by clients' incoming,
- incoming from remote/servers to proxy

  - TCP will typically adjust and behave like the traffic on the clients side.
  - UDP will not have such possibility, unless the application protocol can do it. Eg: if two video feeds over simple UDP arrive from server side and exceed the limit on client side, both clients flows will likely be corrupted. There should be an application feedback to reduce bandwidth, this is out of this scope.

Anyway it would become much more complex, probably involving changes inside shadowsocks, to link remote/server's side traffic to client's side for *tc* usage.

For SOCKS5 clients only sending data, limiting *ingress* from them is required to limit bandwidth, and for SOCKS5 clients only receiving data, limiting *egress* to them is required to limit bandwidth: unless the application in use is well known, both ways should be traffic controlled.

Traffic Control is a complex topic, which I can barely scratch. I'll give two kinds of answers: the simple and crude one doing policing (drop excess) only, and a more complex one, doing shaping (incl. delaying before having to drop), with an IFB interface to work around limitations of *ingress*.

The documentation below should be read to understand the concepts and the Linux implementation:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/

Also this command implemented in shell script (and using similar mechanisms as in this answer) can really do wonders too:

https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper

### Simple and crude

A *police* action is used to drop any excess packet matching ports (which is a crude method). It's usually used in *ingress* but works on *egress* too. Traffic is rate limited, but there might be be fluctuations and unfair sharing among various rate limited clients (especially if UDP vs TCP is involved).

- *egress* (outgoing packets)

  The simpliest *qdisc* allowing to attach filters is the [*prio*](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-prio.8) *qdisc*, whose specific features won't really be used.

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
  ```

  Simply adding the following filter (with 8mbits/s <=> 1MBytes/s) one per port (`u16 at 0 layer transport` means "source port"), will get it done for TCP and UDP <sup>(see also note 2)</sup>:

  ```
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1081)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1082)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  ```

  In case I misunderstood and there should be only one common limit for 1081 and 1082, use this instead of the two above, grouping them in the same action (which is easy with the [basic](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-basic.8)/[ematch](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-ematch.8) filter), which will then handle them in a single token bucket:

  ```
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1081) or cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1082)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  ```
- ingress (incoming packets)

  *Ingress* is more limited than *egress* (can't do *shaping*), but it wasn't done in the simple case anyway. Using it just requires adding an `ingress` qdisc <sup>(see note 3)</sup>:

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
  ```

  The equivalent filters (`u16 at 2 layer transport` means "destination port"):

  ```
  tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1082)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  ```

  or for a single limit, instead of the two above:

  ```
  tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081) or cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1082)' action police rate 8mibit burst 256k
  ```

### Cleaning tc

*egress*, *ingress* or both settings can be replaced with their improved version below. previous settings should be cleaned first.

To remove previously applied tc settings, simply delete the *root* and *ingress* *qdiscs*. Everything below them, including filters, will also be removed. The default interface root *qdisc* with the reserved handle 0: will be put back.

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress
```

### More complex setup with classful qdiscs and IFB interface

The use of *shaping*, which can delay packets before having to drop them should improve overall results. [Hierarchy Token Bucket](http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm) ([HTB](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-htb.8)), a classful qdisc will handle bandwidth, while below it Stochastic Fairness Queueing ([SFQ](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-sfq.8)) will improve fairness between clients when they're competing within the restricted bandwidth.

- egress

  Here's an ascii picture describing the next settings:

  ```
                      root 1:   HTB classful qdisc
                        |
                      / | \
                     /  |  \
                    /   |   \
                   /    |    \
                  /    1:20  1:30  HTB classes
                 /    8mibit  8mibit
                /       |       \
               /        |        \
              /        20:       30:
             /         SFQ       SFQ
       still 1:
       default         port         port
  incl. port 1080      1081         1082
  ```

  The limited bandwidths will not borrow extra available traffic (it was not asked by OP): that's why they aren't a subclass of a "whole available bandwidth" default class. The remaining default traffic, including port 1080, just stays at 1:, with no special handling. In different settings where classes are allowed to borrow available bandwidth, those classes should be put below a parent class having its rate set with an accurate value of the maximum available bandwidth, to know what to borrow. So the configuration would require fine-tuning for each case. I kept it simple.

  The htb classful qdisc:

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
  ```

  The htb classes, attached sfq, and filters directing to them:

  ```
  tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:20 htb rate 8mibit
  tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:30 htb rate 8mibit

  tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10

  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1081)' flowid 1:20
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1082)' flowid 1:30
  ```

  or for a single limit, instead of the 6 commands above:

  ```
  tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:20 htb rate 8mibit
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1081)' flowid 1:20
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport eq 1082)' flowid 1:20
  ```
- ingress

  *Ingress* qdisc can't be used for *shaping* (eg delaying packets) but only to have them dropped with filters like in the simple case. In order to have better control, a trick is available: the [Intermediate Functional Block](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb), which appears as an artificial *egress* interface where *ingress* traffic can be [redirected](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-mirred.8) with filters, but else has little interaction with the rest of the network stack. Once in place, *egress* features can be applied on it, even if some of them might not always be helpful, considering the real control of incoming traffic is not in the hands of the receiving system. So here I setup the `ifb0` interface then duplicate above (*egress*) settings on it, to have sort-of ingress shaping behaving better than just policing.

  Creating *ifb0* <sup>(see note 4)</sup> and applying the same settings as previous *egress*:

  ```
  ip link add name ifb0 type ifb 2>/dev/null || :
  ip link set dev ifb0 up

  tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: htb
  ```

  Classes and filters directing to them:

  ```
  tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:20 htb rate 8mibit
  tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:30 htb rate 8mibit

  tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
  tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10

  tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081)' flowid 1:20
  tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1082)' flowid 1:30
  ```

  or for a single limit, instead if the 6 commands above:

  ```
  tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:20 htb rate 8mibit     
  tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
  tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081)' flowid 1:20
  tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1082)' flowid 1:20
  ```

  The redirection from *eth0*'s *ingress* to *ifb0* *egress* is done below. To optimize, only redirect intended ports instead of all traffic. The actual filtering and shaping is done above in *ifb0* anyway.

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
  tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081)' action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
  tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 1081)' action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
  ```

---

<sub>Notes:</sub>

<sub>1. Tested using a few network namespaces on Debian 10 / kernel 5.3. Commands syntax also tested on CentOS 7.6 container / kernel 5.3 (rather than 3.10)</sub>.

<sub>2. `u32 match ip sport 1081 0xffff` could have been used instead to match source port 1081. But it wouldn't handle the presence of an IP option .`u32 match tcp src 1081 0xffff` could handle it but it actually requires the complex usage of *three* *u32* filters as explained in [the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-u32.8#EXAMPLES). So I chose `basic match` in the end.</sub>

<sub>3. `ingress` has the reserved handle `ffff:` wether specified or not (the specified handle value is ignored), so I'd rather not specify it. Referencing ingress by `parent ffff:` can be replaced by just `ingress` so that's what I chose.</sub>

<sub>4. When creating an IFB interface for the first time, the ifb module gets loaded, which by default automatically creates the *ifb0* and *ifb1* interfaces in initial namespace, resulting in an error if the interface name ifb0 is asked, while it was actually created as a result of the command. At the same time this interface doesn't appear in a network namespace (eg: container) if simply loading the module, so is still needed there. So adding `2>/dev/null || :` solves it for both cases. Of course I'm assuming IFB support is really available.</sub>

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting such a detailed answer at all so thanks. It will take me a while to read through and actually understand it all.

Comment: Just to clarify I did mean that 1081 and 1082 should get 1Mbps each. But maybe someone else with similar needs would want them combined, so it's nice you thought of that too.

Comment: Having studied CS in university myself, it's strange that it never occurred to me that I should be thinking of the problem on a packet level. It's only after you brought it up that I realised doing intermediate-layer traffic control is equivalent to QoS...

Comment: I guess I really dislike the idea of dropping excess packets in my specific application. Reason being SS encrypts and then obfuscates the packets so it would be nearly impossible to create some kind of sensible heuristics that fairly and reasonably drops packets. Also dropped packets often just result in a resend, which simply results in unnecessary network congestion and CPU expense. So I am probably going down the delay route. Also correction to my previous comment: 1MBps not Mb.

Comment: Some dropping can still happen, especially for incoming anyway, but less. My answer has always layers of improvements to be done, that's why I tried to explain a bit. For example wondershaper attempts to give priority to small packets, avoiding congesting simple TCP ACKs without data with an other flow having data going the other way around (the infamous "uploading lowers downloading")