# Problem of limit bandwidth on a specific port in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: networking, iptables, tc

I set up a socks proxy server listening on 2 ports, 10001-10002.

The port 10001 is provided to anonymous user. So, I want to limit the max bandwidth to 1 MB/s, and limit the max bandwidth of port 10002 to 10 MB/s.

I followed the answers here  [Limit bandwidth on a specific port in CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545033/limit-bandwidth-on-a-specific-port-in-centos-7/)

User A.B showed us 2 methods, and I tried the first **simple and crude** approach.

At last, I got a strange result, here is my step:

1. type shell code at server side (Ubuntu 18.04):

   ```
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress handle ffff:
   tc filter add dev eth0 ingress protocol ip basic match 'cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 33322)' action police rate 8mbit burst 256k
   ```
2. setup iperf3 server model on my Ubuntu 18.04:

   ```
   iperf3 -s -p 33322
   ```
3. On my Windows 10, I run an iperf3 client (Ubuntu and Windows 10 in the same local network with 1Gbit bandwidth):

   ```
   iperf3 -c <my server ip> -p 33322
   ```

My client and server screenshots shown below:

[image]

[image]

It seems that the network is only going to have speed at the beginning of the connection, and then the speed is going to be zero, and I don't know why?

After that I limit bandwidth at port 22 on my Ubuntu; then used sFTP on my Windows 10 to upload a big file. The result is same; it has a speed about 100 kB/s at the beginning of the connection, and then the speed decreases until reaches the zero.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: I cut/pasted what you wrote and did as you did between two physical systems connected with a physical 1gbits switch  (except for the server IP and the fact that both systems are Linux Debian running a 5.6.x kernel): I get between 3 and 7.7 Mbits/sec traffic per run when running the same `iperf3 -c <my server ip> -p 33322` (rarely with a temporary stall that recovers). Could be a different behaviour with Windows (tcp window size etc.)... Don't post pictures. Windows too allows you to  cut/paste text from the cmd window. and last: policing ingress is not good compared to shaping egress.