# can I use multiple qdiscs per device?

Tags: linux, networking, tc

Can I add multiple qdiscs to the same device with tc, or is it only possible to use one qdisc per device?

Also, can a qdisc contain child qdiscs, or only child classes?
i.e.
is it possible to do `tc qdisc add parent <existing qdisc> handle <child qdisc> <qdisc type>` ?

Comment: Also check "ethtool". You might have to add some channels with "ethtool -L ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual problem to solve in OP's question, so I'll provide a *very simple* example that uses network namespaces

- set up communications

  ```
  ip -n test1 link add up type veth peer netns test2
  ip -n test2 link set veth0 up
  ip -n test1 address add 192.0.2.11/24 dev veth0
  ip -n test2 address add 192.0.2.12/24 dev veth0
  ```
- initial test

  ```
  # ip netns exec test1 ping -c1 192.0.2.12
  PING 192.0.2.12 (192.0.2.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.0.2.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms

  --- 192.0.2.12 ping statistics ---
  1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.068/0.068/0.068/0.000 ms
  ```
- add a first basic qdisc: *netem*

  ```
  tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 root handle 1: netem delay 100ms
  ```
- test the result

  ```
  # ip -n test1 neigh flush all
  # ip netns exec test1 ping -c2 192.0.2.12
  PING 192.0.2.12 (192.0.2.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.0.2.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=200 ms
  64 bytes from 192.0.2.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=100 ms

  --- 192.0.2.12 ping statistics ---
  2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 100.152/150.223/200.294/50.071 ms
  ```

  (first ping gets the ARP delay in addition to the IP delay that's why it's twice the delay)
- add again a qdisc with the previous as parent

  ```
  tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 parent 1: handle 2: netem delay 350ms
  ```
- test yet again

  ```
  # ip -n test1 neigh flush all
  # ip netns exec test1 ping -c2 192.0.2.12
  PING 192.0.2.12 (192.0.2.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.0.2.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=900 ms
  64 bytes from 192.0.2.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=450 ms

  --- 192.0.2.12 ping statistics ---
  2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 450.228/675.272/900.317/225.044 ms
  ```

  As you can see the two *netem* qdisc were used: 100+350=450ms (and twice because of ARP for the first one)

As long as the qdisc's specific property makes sense, one can continue:

```
tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 parent 2: handle 3: prio
```

until it makes no sense (prio is a *classful* qdisc):

```
# tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 parent 3: handle 4: sfq
Error: Specified class not found.
```

or there is no support (probably because it makes no sense):

```
# tc -n test1 qdisc del dev veth0 parent 2: handle 3:
# tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 parent 2: handle 3: sfq
# tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 parent 3: handle 4: netem delay 100ms
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

but one can't add a second qdisc to something (that's why there are classful qdisc providing multiple classes instead):

```
# tc -n test1 qdisc add dev veth0 root handle 5: netem delay 100ms
Error: NLM_F_REPLACE needed to override.
```

Conclusion:

- yes there can be multiple *qdiscs* per device in total, but at a given hierarchy, there is only one *qdisc*. To have multiple qdiscs "at the same level" would require a *qdisc* which provides multiple *classes* that can each be parent of a *qdisc*.
- and (only non-classful) *qdisc* can have an other *qdisc* as child.

In most useful cases, one uses a *classful* qdisc with *classes*, additional qdiscs added with the *classes* as parent, and there are *filters* to choose how classes will be selected.

Here's a Q/A where I made an answer with this scheme in the second part: [Limit bandwidth on a specific port in CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545033/limit-bandwidth-on-a-specific-port-in-centos-7)